# Yii changing functionality of fullcalendar-scheduler

Tags: yii, fullcalendar-scheduler

I'am using fullcalendarscheduler widget posted on github by Edofre im my yii2 project.
Is there any way i could change predefined rooms displayed in the table into a data from the database.

How it looks now:

```
'resources'         => [
        ['id' => 'a', 'title' => 'Auditorium A'],
        ['id' => 'b', 'title' => 'Auditorium B', 'eventColor' => 'green'],
        ['id' => 'c', 'title' => 'Auditorium C', 'eventColor' => 'orange'],
        [
            'id'       => 'd', 'title' => 'Auditorium D',
            'children' => [
                ['id' => 'd1', 'title' => 'Room D1'],
                ['id' => 'd2', 'title' => 'Room D2'],
            ],
        ],
        ['id' => 'e', 'title' => 'Auditorium E'],

    ],
```

How i could imagine this would work:

```
'resources' => [
    foreach ($rooms as $key) {
        ['id' => $rooms[$key]->id, 'title' => $rooms[$key]->room],
    }
],
```

Edit:
I have learned that i can return data using function:

```
$model = Workers::findAll(['user_id' => 16]);
         $table=[];
         foreach ($model as $key) {
             $work = new Resource(["id" => "a", "title" => $key->imie]);
             $table = $work;
         }

        return [
                $table,
            ];
        }
```

But its only displaying the last record from the table.
What should i do to display entire table with $table variable?

Comment: You should use `$table[] = $work` if you want to create list of objects. Right now every iteration of your foreach overrides previous value of `$table`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. How can i return entire list? return [$table]; dosnt seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$model = Workers::findAll(['user_id' => 16]);
         $table=[];
         foreach ($model as $key) {
             $table[] = ["id" => "a", "title" => $key->imie];
         }

        return $table;
        //return [$table];
```

try these returns

Comment: Thanks, that is what i need